# Access VBA Search Loop

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently making an search loop in VBA for my database. In this database I Have 2 Tables, one with the customers records called `Main` and another one with search words called `Sparr`. The idea is to use a filter to filter out the customers that match any of the search words in the `Sparr` table. Any customer that does not match any of the search words gets added to another table called `filteredCustomerT`.

For example:

```
table "Main"
Field "Mail"
mike@coolmail.com
john@hotmail.com
dave@mail.com
jonny@mailx.com

table "Sparr"
Field "sparrord"
hotmail
jonny

table "Testtable"
Field "testMail"
mike@coolmail.com
dave@mail.com
```

So if I run this VBA code I want `john@hotmail.com` and `jonny@mailx.com` to be filtered out. The `Main` table contains 200k records and the `Sparr` table contains 2k search words. I have wrote some VBA code that should loop through the `Main` table. For every record in the `Main` table a have another nested loop that loops through the `Sparr` table so see if there is any match. If there is not a match the VBA code copies the entry to anther table called `Testtable`. I Use the `inStr` function to do the matching.

Below I have posted the VBA code that does not seem to work. Can anyone help me ant maybe point out a fault in the code. I am very new to VBA programming.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub filter()

Dim mainMail As Recordset
Dim sparrSokord As Recordset
Dim testtableTestmail As Recordset
Dim mainTemp As String
Dim sparrTemp As String
Dim match As Integer

Set mainMail = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Main")
Set sparrSokord = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Sparr")
Set testtableTestmail = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Testtable")

Do Until mainMail.EOF

        mainTemp = mainMail![Mail]
        match = 0
        sparrSokord.MoveFirst
        Do Until sparrSokord.EOF
            sparrTemp = sparrSokord![sparrord]

            If (InStr(mainTemp, sparrTemp) <> 0) Then
                match = 1
                Exit Do
            End If


            sparrSokord.MoveNext
        Loop

        If (match = 0) Then
            testtableTestmail.AddNew
            testtableTestmail![testMail] = mainTemp
            testtableTestmail.Update
        End If

mainMail.MoveNext

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InStr can operate in unexpected ways is you have nulls/empty strings/etc, involved.

I've noticed that you have nothing resetting the position of `SearchwordWord` back to the beginning of the record set once you reach the end.

Naturally you would do something like `SearchwordWord.MoveFirst` before the `Do Until SearchwordWord.EOF`. It doesn't hurt to do one before the `Do Until customerMail.EOF` either

I'll also note the `Do Until` always executes the contents of the loop, and then checks the condition at the end (which could be giving you unexpected results, especially with `SearchwordWord` being at EOF after the first successful pass of the loop.

You probably want to use a `while`/`wend` instead for both `do until`s (I practically never use them as it is). This is probably the biggest cause of your grief.

Comment: Thank you for the improvement suggestions! Is there a better function to do the comparison between the words than Instr?

Comment: Not really... you just have to be cognizant that nulls/empty strings may not do what you think immediately (set the Return Value section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx as an example - it's for VS2008 but it's probably consistent with VBA)

Comment: I have updated the VBA code and it works now. The only problem is that just does 40k of the 200k records and then crashes. But it removes all the entries that include the search word.

I have updated the code above. 

But it has not te same name as before.

The main table is called "Main" and the field is called "Mail". And the serchword table is called "Sparr" with "sparrord" as its field. And it moves the new entries to "Testtable" with the field "testMail"

Main - Mail
Sparr - sparrord
Testtable - testMail

Answer (score -1):

The problem is now solved. I just had to close some programs and try again with the updated code above. Worked just fine!

Comment: great... if my answer helped mark it accepted and everyone will be able to tell at a glance that your question has been resolved.